# How to toggle <div> show and hide with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
    <div class="warnAA1">
        <span onClick="document.getElementsByClassName('warnAA1')[0].style.display = 'none';">
            <button>&times;</button>
        </span>
        <span onClick="document.getElementsByClassName('warnAA1')[0].style.display = 'content';">
            <button> - </button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

I am making a website and I need a bit of assistance with toggling div being shown and not shown with
`<span>` and `<button>` the thing I am toggling is a div section with search and items underneath it, and it just shows the boxes with the content and I want the users to be able to toggle the visibility. Here's what I have tried:

```
    <div class="warnAA1">
        <span onClick="document.getElementsByClassName('warnAA1')[0].style.display = 'none';">
            <button>&times;</button>
        </span>
        <span onClick="document.getElementsByClassName('warnAA1')[0].style.display = 'content';">
            <button> - </button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

I am just stuck on how to toggle the content being displayed.

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: I think it would make a bit more sense to add the click events to the buttons and not the span elements surrounding them. Also, you shouldn't put the buttons inside the element you're hiding. It would also hide the buttons and prevent the user from showing the div again.

Comment: Id move the buttons outside of the div as when it disappears, so too would the buttons. My html has an example of what I feel would best help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <div class="warnAA1">
  <button onclick="showContent()">&times;</button></span>
  <button onclick="removeContent()"> - </button></span>
  <div class = "content">
    Here is div content
 </div>
 </div>
 <script>
 const warnDiv = document.querySelector('.warnAA1');
 const warnDivContent = warnDiv.querySelector('.content');
 function showContent(){
 warnDivContent.style.display = 'none';
 }
 function removeContent() {
 warnDivContent.style.removeProperty('display');
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do this: I'd highly recommend you use ids to not have to worry about relative position querying multiple elements etc. I've also added a toggle button to show how that can work.

```js
var show = document.getElementById("show");
var hide = document.getElementById("hide");
var warn = document.getElementById("warn");
var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");

show.addEventListener("click", function() {
  warn.classList.remove("hide");
});

hide.addEventListener("click", function() {
  warn.classList.add("hide");
});

// Toggle logic
toggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  warn.classList.toggle("hide");
});
```

```css
.warnAA1 {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  min-height: 200px;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

.warnAA1.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="warn" class="warnAA1">
</div>
<div class="abs">
  <button id="show">Show</button>
  <button id="hide">Hide</button>
  <button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `warn.classList.toggle('hide')` can be used instead of the `if-else` structure. [details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: For some reason I thought that method was only jquery. I can update my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **slideToggle()** method in jQuery to achieve your requirement easily.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").slideToggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div>This is a paragraph.</div><br><br>

<button>Toggle slideUp() and slideDown()</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have both your buttons inside the content you are trying to hide both the buttons hide along with the parent please try the following code snippet and let me know if it works. Placing the buttons outside should fix it.

```js
function Hide(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('warnAA1')[0].style.display = 'none';
}

function Show(){
      document.getElementsByClassName('warnAA1')[0].style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<span onClick="Hide()"><button>&times;</button></span>
<span onClick="Show()"><button> - </button></span>
<div class="warnAA1">
MY content
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't the best solution as it is not D.R.Y. You can easily make a toggle function and pass it with overrides. It also doesn't allow for modification of any styling and would just 'cut' the items in/out, which isn't the greatest UX, IMO. It also presumes that it's the first of that classArray, and doesn't cache the variable needing to parse the DOM every time it's called.